# typedef behaviour in C

Tags: c

Why do I get error in  this code?Even if i do not link but only compile still it gives an error.why does not compiler consider the possibility of  it  being  present in another file?
Could anyone explain how typedef statement is treated by compiler.

Thanks in advance

```
 typedef struct p* q; 

    int main()
    {
     struct p{
      int x;
      char y;
      q ptr;
      }; 
      struct p p={1,2,&p};
      printf("%d\n",p.ptr->ptr->x);
      return 0;
    }
```

ps:dereference to incomplete type is the error i get in gcc.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what error you got?

Comment: You should specify what the error is so people can best understand what's happening.

Comment: `struct p` inside `main` and outside it are DIFFERENT!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “struct p” outside main and the “struct p” inside main are different types because they are defined in different scopes. If you put both declarations outside main or both inside main, the compiler will accept it.

When you define something inside a function, you are saying “Here is a definition I am using just inside this function; it is not applicable to anything outside the function.”